2000s TV childrens animated show - young girls with name like gemstones
I remember little things about the show. I was watching it in around 2002+. There were 3-4 young girls (around age 8-10). They all have names like diamond, emerald, amethyst, sapphire etc.
I remember they have a club/tree house, and when they have a mission they all come into the clubhouse in different ways. I remember one comes down a seated zip wire and another comes down a slide but I don't remember the other. 
They all wears dresses that match their names, e.g. Diamond wears a light blue dress (she's blonde by the way, I remember her and emerald). Emerald wears a green dress, amethyst would wear a purple dress etc.  
The last thing I remember is that the theme song sounds very similar to Hoku's 'perfect day' from Legally Blonde. 

Could it be Trollz? If it is I will add as an answer =)

No it's not, I already checked. Thank you though.

Is it a cartoon or live action?

Not exactly like a cartoon, more of a 3D animation. Like the 'backyardsagains'.

Kind of a shot in the dark here, but is it Steven Universe?  Have a look through the sub-tabs in the character gallery.  The characters are named after gemstones and coloured appropriately, although I wouldn't say most of them look 8-10 years old myself.  Diamond, Emerald and Amethyst (among many others) are all represented here.

@Steve-O that was my guess as well, but it doesn't line up perfectly.

liv, is there anything else you could tell us about the show?  did you watch it on a network or dvd, was it American?

the only other one I found is codename kid next door, maybe you're getting the two mixed up?  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0312109/

@Steve-O No, neither of them are the one. I watched it in the UK in around 2002-2007. I think the show was American, or at least the girls had the accents. I don't remember if it was a channel or not. It could've been VHS, but that's quite unlikely. I'm trying to think if there's anymore information I can give you

@DForck42 Oh and the girls were the main characters of the programme, no one else was really involved. The animation was somewhat like 'Sofia the first'?

I have been going crazy trying to figure it out! Was it by chance Kelly's Dream Club: The Sparkle Fairy Adventure?

Why do you think this might be it? Can you expand on this please?

YES!! That was it! Thank you so much, I have been going insane!! x

@Liv4432 If this is correct, please mark it as correct as by clicking the green tick next to the answer.
